# How to return SSL resource for Facebook Video Embed

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use embed_html from Graph API but the calls are not returning SSL using return_ssl_results=1, is there away to return the embed code for ssl?

Comment: This is a known bug in Facebook's API - it's being worked on btu there's been no update in a while - http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try{} to rewrite the urls of the source before adding to the object.  This worked pretty well for me.

- $fvalue[source] is the source url of a post that contains a video,
- you can do with $fvalue[embed_html] too.

---

```
if($fvalue[source]){
   $reWrite = array("autoplay=1" => "autoplay=0", "http://" => "https://");
   $getEmbed = $fvalue[source];
   $strAuto = strtr($getEmbed, $reWrite);
   echo '<object style="float:left; clear:left; margin: 5px;"><param name="autostart" value="0"><embed autostart="false" src="'.$strAuto.'"></embed></object>';
}
```